# How to use MVVM pattern for Frame navigation in wpf (same View, different VM)?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, frame

I'm developing a crawler program and I want it to have a similar experience to a browser, i.e. I can go back/forward, I'd like to use a Frame control but I'm not sure how to do it, my View is the same, each query is just a different VM.

[image: Demo]

I tried to customize INavigationService and its implementation and basically it works ok. But since objects such as QueryRequest are reference types, they can't maintain their own state when navigating, one solution would be to use deep cloning, but the object may be subscribed to events, and deep cloning doesn't seem to clone the events, and in any case, I need to maintain the entire page state.

If I use the Frame control, I don't need to manage the page state, but it doesn't seem to work logically, how do I navigate to a new page and execute a query when I click the Query button (QueryCommand)? Assuming I do this, the Query in nextView/ViewModel needs to be called, and then it will go into an infinite loop!

Another thing that confuses me is that if I use Google to search for "Foo" in my browser, then search for "Bar", then go-back, why does the search box remember "Foo "? How can I do this in WPF/Frame?

services.AddTransient();
services.AddTransient();

NavigationService:

```cs
public class NavigationService<T> : INavigationService<T> where T : notnull
{
    public Stack<T> BackStack { get; } = [];

    public bool CanGoBack => BackStack.Count > 1;

    public bool CanGoForward => ForwardStack.Count > 0;

    public T? Current { get; private set; }

    public Stack<T> ForwardStack { get; } = [];

    public event EventHandler<NavigationEventArgs<T>>? Navigated;

    public T? GoBack(int step = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < step; i++)
        {
            if (CanGoBack)
            {
                var current = BackStack.Pop();
                ForwardStack.Push(current);
            }
        }

        if (BackStack.TryPeek(out var previous))
        {
            Current = previous;
        }

        OnNavigated();

        return Current;
    }

    public void GoBackTo(T content)
    {
        if (BackStack.Contains(content))
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(BackStack.Peek(), content))
            {
                GoBack();
            }
        }
    }

    public T? GoForward(int step = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < step; i++)
        {
            if (CanGoForward)
            {
                var next = ForwardStack.Pop();
                BackStack.Push(next);
                Current = next;
            }
        }

        OnNavigated();

        return Current;
    }

    public void GoForwardTo(T content)
    {
        if (BackStack.Contains(content))
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(ForwardStack.Peek(), content))
            {
                GoForward();
            }
        }
    }

    public void Navigate(T content, bool replace = false)
    {
        if (replace)
        {
            BackStack.Pop();
        }

        BackStack.Push(content);
        Current = content;
        ForwardStack.Clear();
        OnNavigated();
    }

    protected virtual void OnNavigated()
    {
        Navigated?.Invoke(this, new(Current!, BackStack, ForwardStack));
    }
}
```

QueryViewModel:

```cs
// Bind to Query button command.
[RelayCommand(IncludeCancelCommand = true)]
private async Task QueryAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    try
    {
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var webService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IWebService>();
        QueryResponse = await webService.QueryAsync(QueryRequest, cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        Growl.Info("Cancelled.");
    }
    catch
    {
        QueryResponse = null;

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        _navigationService.Navigate(new QuerySession(
            PageIndex,
            PageSize,
            QueryRequest,
            QueryResponse,
            VerticalScrollOffset), _refreshMode);
    }
}

// Bind to GoBack button command.
[RelayCommand]
private void GoBack()
{
    _isNavigating = true;

    var session = _navigationService.GoBack();

    if (session is not null)
    {
        PageIndex = session.PageIndex;
        PageSize = session.PageSize;
        QueryRequest = session.QueryRequest;
        QueryResponse = session.QueryResponse;
        VerticalScrollOffset = session.VerticalScrollOffset;
    }

    _isNavigating = false;
}

// Omitted GoForward、Refresh...
```

Comment: You will have **two** views: 1. The Window 2. The Page inside the Frame

Comment: BTW the Frame already has a complete Navigation with a stack etc.

Comment: You will find an example project with page navigation @ https://github.com/SirRufo/so-77657479-PageNavigation

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Sir Rufo, I implemented my own version (dirty, may not be for everyone):

My Page is `KeepAlive=True`, and the Frame is cleared out of the ForwardStack if it backs up and then re-navigates after, but the Page/Vm doesn't seem to be dispose. So I'm now working on fixing the memory leak when the ForwardStack is empty.

**Edit: Eventually I gave up on using the Frame approach and used the original version in the question (i.e. single Page, maintaining a VM-state Back/ForwardStack), the Frame approach had a serious memory leak and I tried a few things that still didn't help (setting `KeepAlive=False`, manual `GC.Collcet()`, `Frame.RemoveBackEntry()` method).**

```cs
public class FrameX : Frame
{
    public FrameX()
    {
        Navigated += FrameX_Navigated;
    }

    private static void SetValue<T, TValue>(T obj, string propertyName, TValue value) where T : notnull
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        if (type.IsInterface)
        {
            type = obj.GetType();
        }

        var backingField = type.GetField(
            $"<{propertyName}>k__BackingField",
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
            ?? throw new ArgumentException($"Property {propertyName} not found in type {type.FullName}.");

        backingField.SetValue(obj, value);
    }

    private void FrameX_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var navigatablePage = (NavigatablePage)e.Content;

        if (!navigatablePage.IsNavigated)
        {
            SetValue(navigatablePage, nameof(NavigatablePage.NavigationEventArgs), e);

            var navigator = (INavigator)navigatablePage.DataContext;
            SetValue(navigator, nameof(INavigator.NavigationService), NavigationService);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public interface INavigatablePage
{
    bool IsNavigated { get; }

    bool IsNavigating { get; }

    NavigationEventArgs NavigationEventArgs { get; }

    INavigator Navigator { get; }
}
```

```cs
// KeepAlive="True" in xaml
public abstract class NavigatablePage : Page, INavigatablePage
{
    public bool IsNavigated { get; protected set; }

    public bool IsNavigating { get; protected set; }

    public NavigationEventArgs NavigationEventArgs { get; } = null!;

    public INavigator Navigator { get; }

    protected NavigatablePage()
    {
        Navigator = App.Current.Services.GetRequiredService<INavigator>();
        DataContext = Navigator;
        Loaded += NavigatablePage_Loaded;
        Unloaded += NavigatablePage_Unloaded;
    }

    protected virtual async Task NavigatedToAsync(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsNavigated)
        {
            IsNavigating = true;

            try
            {
                IsNavigated = true;
                await Navigator.OnNavigatedToAsync(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsNavigating = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual async Task OnLoadedAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await NavigatedToAsync(NavigationEventArgs);
    }

    protected virtual async Task OnUnloadedAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Loaded -= NavigatablePage_Loaded;
        Unloaded -= NavigatablePage_Unloaded;

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async void NavigatablePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await OnLoadedAsync(sender, e);
    }

    private async void NavigatablePage_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await OnUnloadedAsync(sender, e);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```cs
public partial class QueryViewModel : INavigator
{
    public async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(NavigationEventArgs navigationState)
    {
       // Perform query.
    }

    private void OnQueryButtonClickCommand()
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new DerivedNavigatablePage(), navigationState);
    }
}
```